# Approach when boosting performance with Async/ Await C#

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm, async-await

In my WPF application which follows MVVM, I have the following code in my view model. What it does is quite simply open up a window which has a DataGrid by populating some data in it.

This works as it is but the problem is with performance. More the no. of items to be loaded increases, more time it takes to execute this `OpenWindow()` method, hence it takes a long time for the window to open. This can be quite frustrating from a users point where he/she clicks the button and its takes a good 15-20 seconds until something appears on screen.

I'm trying to map the concepts of C#'s Async/ Await as a solution to my problem but would really appreciate some direction as I'm fairly new to this.

The ideal solution would be to Open up even an empty window ASAP on click ( that means that the `OpenWindow()` method will complete execution while the methods inside of it are running in parallel) and eventually add in the required data ( which comes from the 2 methods `GetData` and `AddData`). My code is below, any ideas of suggestions would be very helpful

```
public async Task OpenWindow()
{
    // A window with some data would open by the end of executing this method
    
    await GetData();
    // After the above has successfully executed I have all the data I need
    AddData(Items);
}

private async Task<IEnumerable<ContentObject>> GetData()
{
    // Quite a time consuming server call, something like 
    var result = await Server.Call(z => z.GetData(request));
    return result? .ToList();
    // Needs to execute prior to AddData method from the caller since it get some data to be added
}
private void AddData(IEnumerable<ItemType> items)
{
    AllItemList = new ObservableCollection<ItemModel>();

    // Adds each item to an observable collection which is intended to populate a datagrid
    // Some items are from the IEnumerable<ItemType> items but some data are obtained from the server call in the previous method which is why its awaited
    // It is OK that this method carries out operations after the window has been opened.

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var currentItem = new ItemModel
        {
            ID =  item.id,
            Name = item.Name
        };

        AllItemList.Add(currentTask);
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged("AllItemList");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need an ObservableCollection at all? You only seem to be recreating the AllItemList without adding or removing elements later. How many items are there?

Comment: @Clemens Yes I need to have an ObservableCollection since my datagrid is populated with ItemsSource="{Binding AllItemList,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True }"

Comment: That does not require an ObservableCollection when you only create a new collection. ObservableCollection would only be need when you later add or remove elements to/from the existing collection. Also note that UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged is pointless. It has no effect at all. Also NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True only makes sense when you attach a handler to the Binding's SourceUpdated event, which you don't do.

Comment: So all you need to write is `ItemsSource="{Binding AllItemList}"`.

Comment: Thats not possible, AllItemList contains some properties from the "Items" and some of which is obtained from the server call, I've mentioned in the question above :) 
Which is why I'm looking for a way to open up the window ASAP

Answer (score 0):

> The ideal solution would be to Open up even an empty window ASAP on click ( that means that the OpenWindow() method will complete execution while the methods inside of it are running in parallel) and eventually add in the required data ( which comes from the 2 methods GetData and AddData).

I recommend using the technique from [my article on Asynchronous MVVM: Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/march/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-data-binding) (updated code is [here](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm/blob/d90b2a0e4792a450549f3770e7886275c3ccb0fc/future/Nito.Mvvm.Async/NotifyTask.cs)). Then you have something like this:

```
public NotifyTask<ObservableCollection<ItemModel>> AllItemList { get; private set; }

public MyWindow()
{
  AllItemList = NotifyTask.Create(async () => AddData(await GetData()));
}

private ObservableCollection<ItemModel> AddData(IEnumerable<ItemType> items)
{
  var result = new ObservableCollection<ItemModel>();

  foreach (var item in items)
  {
    var currentItem = new ItemModel
    {
      ID =  item.id,
      Name = item.Name
    };

    result.Add(currentTask);
  }

  return result;
}
```

`NotifyTask<T>` has properties you can bind to, including `Result` (a `T` value), `IsSuccessfullyCompleted`, `IsFaulted`, and `ErrorMessage`.

Answer (score -2):

Using TPL (tasks, async, await) to fetch data asynchronously is a great idea to improve your WPF app. However, be aware that changes to your view model need to be made from the main thread, otherwise your databinding will not work. You can use the application Dispatcher to invoke your AddData function on the main thread; however, be sure that the main thread is not blocked waiting on one of your async methods to complete.

[This blog](https://michaelscodingspot.com/c-deadlocks-in-depth-part-2/) has some great examples of ways to use the Dispatcher to ensure that your `AllItemList` is updated from the main thread.  It could look something like this:

```cs
private void AddData(IEnumerable<ItemType> items)
{
    // this code will be run on the UI thread as soon as it is available
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (() =>
    {
        AllItemList = new ObservableCollection<ItemModel>();
        // ...
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged("AllItemList");
    }));
}
```

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - Good point. It sounded like the OP wasn't planning on awaiting OpenWindow(). If they did, the invoke would be unnecessary.